# Get ElementName of Binding from XAML through code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

This is an XAML snippet from my project:

```
 <TextBox x:Name="txt_Time1" LostFocus="TextBox_LoseFocus">
    <TextBox.Text>
    <Binding Converter="{StaticResource timezoneconverter}" 
     ElementName="cmb_TZ1" Path="SelectedValue"/>
    </TextBox.Text>
 </TextBox>
```

In my code here:

```
      private void TextBox_LoseFocus(object Sender, EventArgs e)
         {
         var txtBox = Sender as TextBox;
```

**My Question is:** Is it possible to get the ElementName of this TextBox through code?

EDIT: To add to this question in order to make it rounded.

  **How can this be done in a MultiBinding scenario?**

```
 <TextBox x:Name="txt_Time1" LostFocus="TextBox_LostFocus" >
          <TextBox.Text>
              <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource timezoneconverter}">
              <Binding ElementName="cmb_TZ1" Path="SelectedValue"/>
              <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="Text"/>
              </MultiBinding>
          </TextBox.Text>
      </TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For retrieving the Element Name in plain Binding :

```
  BindingExpression bindingExpression =   
  txtBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
  Binding parentBinding = bindingExpression.ParentBinding;
  String elementName = parentBinding.ElementName;
```

In a Multi Binding Scenario :

```
 MultiBindingExpression multiBindingExpression = BindingOperations.GetMultiBindingExpression(txtBox, TextBox.TextProperty);
 Binding parentBinding = ((BindingExpression)multiBindingExpression.BindingExpressions[0]).ParentBinding;
 String elementName = parentBinding.ElementName;
```

Answer (score 2):

`BindingOperations.GetBinding(...)` will give you the `Binding`, and `ElementName` is the property of `Binding` class.

Answer (score 1):

BindingExpression bindingExpression = textBox1.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
Binding parentBinding = bindingExpression.ParentBinding;

Comment: Any idea how this can be done in a MultiBinding scenario?

Comment: For multi binding you can use following code:
`MultiBinding bindingExpression = BindingOperations.GetMultiBinding(txtSample, TextBox.TextProperty);
Collection<BindingBase> parentBinding = bindingExpression.Bindings;`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this,

```
  private void txt_Time_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var txtBox = sender as TextBox;
            Binding myBinding = BindingOperations.GetBinding(txt_Time, TextBox.TextProperty);
            var elementName = myBinding.ElementName;
        }
```